I have a DropDownMenu in a dialog. When the keyboard pops up, the dropdown is pushed up while the list is left behind
I have a DropDownMenu in a dialog. When the keyboard pops up, the dropdown is pushed up while the list is left behind.

I have tried tinkering the properties and stuff but nothing. I am fairly new to flutter and working on first project. Bear with my code. haven't started refactoring yet so there is a lot of repetition.
Dialog(
        insetPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Form(
              canPop: true,
              key: _paymentsFormKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: DropdownMenu<String>(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      inputDecorationTheme: dropdownDecoration,
                      // hintText: 'Select transaction type',
                      initialSelection: list.first,
                      onSelected: (String? value) {
                        print(value);
                        // This is called when the user selects an item.
                        setState(() {
                          transactionType = value!;
                          print(
                              'llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll');
                          print(transactionType);
                        });
                      },
                      dropdownMenuEntries:
                          list.map<DropdownMenuEntry<String>>((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                side: WidgetStateProperty.all<BorderSide>(
                                  BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: .5),
                                ),
                                foregroundColor: WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(
                                    Colors.grey.shade600),
                                backgroundColor:
                                    const WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(
                                        Colors.white)),
                            value: value,
                            label: value);
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
                    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('users/$adeer/accounts')
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return TextField(
                            decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                              label: const Text('Account from'),
                            ),
                          );
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                        } else {
                          var accounts = snapshot.data!.docs;
                          List<DropdownMenuEntry<String>> dropdownEntries =
                              accounts.map((account) {
                            //Get the fields from firestore
                            var fullName = account['full name'];
                            var kesBalance = account['kes balance'] as double;
                            var usdBalance = account['usd balance'] as double;
                            // Format the numbers with comas using intl
                            final formatter = NumberFormat("#,##0.00");
                            String formattedKesBalance =
                                formatter.format(kesBalance);
                            String formattedUsdBalance =
                                formatter.format(usdBalance);

                            //Assign colors. If negative -color red else grey
                            Color kesBalanceColor = kesBalance < 0
                                ? Colors.red.shade400
                                : Colors.grey.shade600;
                            Color usdBalanceColor = usdBalance < 0
                                ? Colors.red.shade400
                                : Colors.grey.shade600;

                            return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                  side: WidgetStateProperty.all<BorderSide>(
                                    BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade300, width: .5),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                value: '$fullName',
                                labelWidget: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  child: Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        '$fullName ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.grey.shade600),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        ' KES',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            letterSpacing: 1.5,
                                            // fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                            color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '$formattedKesBalance,  ',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: kesBalanceColor,
                                          letterSpacing: 1.5,
                                          // fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                          // color:
                                          //     Colors.grey.shade600
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        ' USD',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            letterSpacing: 1.5,
                                            // fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                            color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '$formattedUsdBalance',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            letterSpacing: 1.5,
                                            // fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                            color: usdBalanceColor),
                                      ),
                                      // Divider(),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                label: '$fullName'
                                // label: '$firstName',
                                );
                          }).toList();

                          return DropdownMenu(
                            // errorText: 'This field is required',
                            menuStyle: const MenuStyle(
                              // padding: WidgetStateProperty.all<
                              //     EdgeInsetsGeometry>(
                              //   const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              //       horizontal:
                              //           20.0), // Apply vertical and horizontal padding
                              // ),
                              backgroundColor:
                                  WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(Colors.white),
                            ),
                            controller: _fromAccountController,
                            // expandedInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            requestFocusOnTap: true,
                            label: const Text(
                              'Account from',
                            ),
                            // enableFilter: true,
                            enableSearch: true,
                            menuHeight: 200,
                            inputDecorationTheme: dropdownDecoration,
                            dropdownMenuEntries: dropdownEntries,
                            onSelected: (String? value) {},
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: _receiverController,
                            cursorErrorColor: Colors.black54,

                            // onFieldSubmitted: (_) =>
                            //     widget.nextFocusNode?.requestFocus(),
                            inputFormatters: [
                              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                  32), // Limit the number of characters

                              FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('[0-9]')),
                            ],
                            decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                              errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0),
                              label: const Text(
                                'Receiver full name',
                                // style:
                                // TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                              ),
                            ),
                            validator: (String? value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'This field is required';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                            0,
                            0,
                            5,
                            5,
                          ),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: _receiverIdController,
                            inputFormatters: [
                              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                  12), // Limit the number of characters
                            ],
                            decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                              label: const Text(
                                'Receiver\'s ID',
                              ),
                            ),
                            validator: (String? value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'This field is required';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  if (transactionType == 'Pay USD')
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 5),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 45,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _payUsdController,
                          cursorErrorColor: Colors.black54,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                9), // Limit the number of characters

                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
                          ],
                          decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0),
                            label: const Text(
                              'Pay USD amount',
                              // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ),
                          validator: (String? value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'This field is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (transactionType == 'USD bank deposit')
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 5),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 45,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _usdBankDepositController,
                          cursorErrorColor: Colors.black54,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                9), // Limit the number of characters

                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
                          ],
                          decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0),
                            label: const Text(
                              'Dollar deposit amount',
                              // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ),
                          validator: (String? value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'This field is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (transactionType == 'Pay KES')
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 5),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _payKesController,
                        cursorErrorColor: Colors.black54,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                              9), // Limit the number of characters

                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
                        ],
                        decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                          errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0),
                          label: const Text(
                            'Pay Ksh amount',
                            // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                          ),
                        ),
                        validator: (String? value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'This field is required';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (transactionType == 'KES bank deposit')
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 5),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 45,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _kesBankDepositController,
                          cursorErrorColor: Colors.black54,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                9), // Limit the number of characters

                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
                          ],
                          decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0),
                            label: const Text(
                              'KES deposit amount',
                              // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ),
                          validator: (String? value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'This field is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (transactionType == "Transfer KES")
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 5),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 45,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _transferKESController,
                          cursorErrorColor: Colors.black54,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                9), // Limit the number of characters

                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
                          ],
                          decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0),
                            label: const Text(
                              'Transfer KES amount',
                              // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ),
                          validator: (String? value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'This field is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (transactionType == "Transfer USD")
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 5),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 45,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _transferUsdController,
                          cursorErrorColor: Colors.black54,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                9), // Limit the number of characters

                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
                          ],
                          decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0),
                            label: const Text(
                              'Transfer USD amount',
                              // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ),
                          validator: (String? value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'This field is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  if (transactionType == "Pay an expense")
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 3, 5, 5),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 45,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          controller: _expenseController,
                          cursorErrorColor: Colors.black54,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                                9), // Limit the number of characters

                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
                          ],
                          decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0),
                            label: const Text(
                              'Expense amount',
                              // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                            ),
                          ),
                          validator: (String? value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'This field is required';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 3, 5, 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _remarksController,
                      cursorErrorColor: Colors.black54,
                      maxLines: 3,
                      minLines: 1,
                      inputFormatters: [
                        LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(
                            50), // Limit the number of characters
                      ],
                      decoration: kInputDecoration.copyWith(
                        //
                        errorStyle: const TextStyle(height: 0),
                        label: const Text(
                          'Remarks',
                          // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                        ),
                      ),
                      validator: (String? value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'This field is required';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        const Gap(20),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          style: const ButtonStyle(
                            foregroundColor:
                                WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(Colors.white),
                            backgroundColor:
                                WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(secondaryColor),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          child: const Text('Cancel'),
                        ),
                        const Gap(10),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          style: const ButtonStyle(
                            foregroundColor:
                                WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(Colors.white),
                            backgroundColor:
                                WidgetStatePropertyAll<Color>(primaryColor),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_fromAccountController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                                _paymentsFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              _showApprovalDialog();
                            } else {
                              showDialog<String>(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    const CustomAlertDialog(),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                          child: const Text('Submit'),
                          // child: const Text('Submit'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Gap(20),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));

